# CMake, QT Creator - projects bar doesn't display folders

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I created a QT project with QMake. I have two files. `somewidget.h` and `somewidget.cpp` in the same folder as `.pro` file. Then I created a folder `SomeFolder` and here I created two files `someclass.h` and `someclass.cpp`. I see the Project panel on the sidebar:
[image]

I see the files in the folder, that I created.

---

Then I did the same, but with CMake:
[image]
But QT Creator doesn't display my folder. There is just a list of header and source files. I deleted all QT configs, reinstalled QT Creator, but nothing has changed. How to fix it?
P.S. I didn't try use `add_subdirectory`, but anyway I don't want to create `CMakeLists` in each folder. I use `Qt Creator 4.11.0 Based on Qt 5.12.8 (GCC 9.3.0, 64 bit)`
`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
 
project(testing LANGUAGES CXX)
 
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
 
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
 
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
 
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Network REQUIRED)
 
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/somewidget.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/somewidget.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/somefolder/someclass.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/somefolder/someclass.cpp
)
 
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in `QT Creator 4.11.0`. The latest version 4.13.0 doesn't have this problem.